# Find Column Groups in Data

Tags: python, sql, excel

I have an excel file with Data of users who visited specific screens on an App.
eg.
[image]

I need to figure out a way to find multiple screen group users

eg.

[image]

The number of unique screens are 6 so manually making this list isn't scalable with all permutations and combinations.

Tools available are excel and python and sql.

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired output

Comment: Data is confidential. Can you please ask questions with respect to the sample I've explained above?

Comment: The actual data is not required, you may replace `ABC` with `QWE` and it will not change anything. Please post the data in tabular format (as you have it in your database) and what you expect in tabular format also

Comment: Done - Let me know if you have follow up questions

Comment: What is your DBMS? You need to group by each category and user, then use DBMS-specific flavor of `group_concat` aggregate function (`group_concat/string_agg/listagg` depending on the DBMS) grouping by user_id and then group by that aggregated string

Comment: I only have exported excel file. I can however run queries on this data by creating this into  a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You not provided your RDBMS version, but in common case you can aggregate activity types by user_id. Below query for MySQL:

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT activity_type ORDER BY activity_type ASC) activities
FROM log
GROUP BY user_id
order by activities;
```

[sql editor online](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql57/ce3eed79315be1c3ae64801174ddc749/)

Result:
✓ (2 queries)

```
+=========+==============+
| user_id | activities   |
+=========+==============+
| 2       | Front        |
+---------+--------------+
| 1       | Front,Splash |
+---------+--------------+
| 3       | Load         |
+---------+--------------+
| 5       | Load         |
+---------+--------------+
| 4       | Load,Splash  |
+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thank You, exactly what I wanted!